# Working in the Netherlands

Tags: romanian-citizens

I am a 21 years old Romanian, considering working in the Netherlands, preferably Amsterdam. I have no other work experience than two months as a Guest Experience Leader at a McDonald's. I possess a high-school diploma and a baccalaureate diploma as well, and I am proficient, to say the least, in English. Are there any chances for me to find work, not necessarily with relocation included, but a job and a place to live where the rent doesn't break my back?

Comment: I don't know about work exactly but unemployment in the Netherlands is low. Rent and accommodation are likely to be a bigger problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any chances for me to find work

Yes.  Many Romanians work in The Netherlands in many different jobs.  There are shortages in many sectors, including those that don't need a lot of training.  With the staff shortages in the hospitality business, I have noticed many hotel and restaurant staff in Amsterdam do not speak Dutch, so apparently speaking English is enough nowadays.

> where the rent doesn't break my back

No.  The rent will break your back unless you're willing to live in very poor and cramped standards.